# Simple search in MySql

Tags: mysql, select, search, innodb, sql-like

I'm trying to create a basic search functionality for MySQL InnoDB. I know there is Full-text search, but I just want to make an easy and simple solution for now. What I want is that when a user search for example "BMW Car" I want to find results not just like "BMW Car" but also "Car BMW" "BMW Z4 Car" and so on.. Is there an easy way to do this? How would you implement a search like this?

Right now I'm using LIKE:

```
SELECT title,id FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%BMW Car%'
```

But that will not give me results like "Car BMW" "BMW Z4 Car"..

Answer (score 1):

You can work with two LIKEs:

```
SELECT title,id FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%BMW%' AND title LIKE '%Car%'
```

If there weren't the need to change the server's configuration to [reduce the minimum key word size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) from 4 to 3 to match `BMW`, I'd say you'd be better off with [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) in [boolean mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) from the start. It is so much more flexible:

```
SELECT title,id FROM table WHERE MATCH (title)
AGAINST ('+BMW +Car -Volvo' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

full-text search can also search for phrases:

```
SELECT title,id FROM table WHERE MATCH (title)
AGAINST ('+"BMW Z4" -"BMW Z3"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: @Martin you're right of course, I overlooked that part. Sorry. FWIW, [here's](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,12604,12956#msg-12956) a description of how Wikipedia seems to work around it (the whole thread there is interesting). LIKE seems indeed to be the easiest way

Comment: Any ideas if InnoDB will include full-text search in the future? I really like the simplicity of the full-text code above!

Comment: @Martin no idea, according to the conversation I link to, it was promised for January 2006... But it's 2010 and it's still not there. Keeping a myISAM duplicate for search purposes is probably the best one can do

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the logical operators in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/logical-operators.html

```
# Title must contain either "bmw" or "car"
SELECT title, id FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%bmw%' OR title LIKE '%car%'

#Title must contain both "bmw" and "car"
SELECT title, id FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%bmw%' AND title LIKE '%car%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will take some pre-processing to split the user input up into words. In php, you could do:

```
$sql = "SELECT title,id FROM table WHERE " ;
$or = "" ;
$inputs = explode(" ", $_GET['q']) ;
foreach($inputs as $input) {
    if(trim($input)=="") continue ;
    $sql .= $or."title LIKE '%".sprintf("%s", mysql_real_escape_string($input))."%' " ;
    $or = "OR " ;
}
$result = mysql_query($sql) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using Lucene for search functionality like this.  It's entire existence revolves around searching documents.  You'd get a document ID back (which would represent your tables PK) and then select out of the DB using that.